# Remove IAP store from game = rejection?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I decided to remove a button in my game so that users won't be able to access the IAP store. I plan to submit my game with the In-App Purchase tab turned on in Xcode(I want to leave the codes there for future use and the game won't work if I turn it off), but without the app really having an IAP store. Will the app get rejected like this?

Answer (score 1):

IAP is on by default, same is GameCenter. If you do not use them, the app will not get rejected.

If you enable them, that does not mean that you have to use them or are currently using them.